# Couldn't assign value in FileUpload tool

Tags: c#, asp.net

I grabbed the value from database and I am trying to assign those values in Edit Form. But the only problem is with the FileUpload. It don't take the value. Can anyone suggest me what I'm missing here

```
private void EditForDataByID(int TitleId)
    {


        ReadmoreController objFormController = new ReadmoreController();
        ReadMoreInfo objInfo = objFormController.GetListObjectOfAllArticle(TitleId);
        if (objInfo != null)
        {
            TextTitle.Text = objInfo.Title;
            txtSummary.Text = objInfo.Summary;
            TextDate.Text = objInfo.Date.ToString();

            //FileUpload1.FileName=objInfo.Image;  I even tried this but it doesn't work 

            FileUpload1 = objInfo.Image;

            Session["TitleId"] = TitleId;
            ListDiv.Visible = false;
            form.Visible = true;
            BindGrid();



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For client security reason you can `not` assign value to `FileUploadControl` as it could cause the uploading of unwanted files from client machine. So let the use pick the file to upload.

If it is allowed then one can **steel** the important files from client machine like `c:\PersonalPasswords`

**Edit** Based on comments

If you need to ensure that user has selected an Image and does not need to change it then you can use a image control and assign image to it. Use the same image control to find if the image is selected or not.

Comment: thanx for comment. What I am trying to do is show all the previous value in edit form and user can edit which ever field they like. So if user don't want to change the previous image( i.e. saved in database) then in such case I can't force user to upload new image. So there gotta be some way just to display the value in FileUpload (if yes then pls do share, I gotta solve this soon)